# Why isnt a static variable in activity not getting updated when activity isnt in foreground

Tags: android

I have an activity- `MainActivity` and a service- `MainService` (in manifest declared the service to run in another process)

In `MainService`(implements `LocationListener`) I have:

1. in `onStartCommand()` - I am getting the longitude and latitude value and sending it in broadcast as extra value. doing the same for `onLocationChanged()`

In `MainActivity`:

1. two `static double` variable- `latitud` & `longitud`
2. Start Button - Starting the service. registering for broadcast receiver with below method.

   ```
    private void strtBrdCast()  {

        IntentFilter intntFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intntFilter.addAction("MyBroadcast");

       mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() 
       {
           @Override
           public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
           {
               latitud = intent.getDoubleExtra("xLat",0);
               longitud = intent.getDoubleExtra("xLon",0);

               txtVwLati.setText(String.valueOf(latitud));
               txtVwLongi.setText(String.valueOf(longitud));
           }
       };
       //registering our receiver
       this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, intntFilter);
   }
   ```
3. Stop Button - to stop the service.
4. `onResume()` of activity: checking for my service. If the service is available than setting the longitude latitude value from the static variables to the `textBoxes`.

its working fine-when I send locations using Emulator control. Even the service is still available when I press back button and come back to the activity. But the static variables are not getting updated and not showing value of location in `textBoxes`.

Is it because if activity isn't on foreground than it cant receive any broadcasts?

I have also tried to update the static variables of activity from service-in `onLocationChanged()`. Doesn't work either.

--------Edited----------

If i use static variable inside my service class and retrieve them on onResume() of activity. Why isn't it working too?

Comment: You say you are using static variables but the code you provide does not show any of that.

Comment: user3870105 Please provide some more data

Comment: under main Activity number-1 point. And inside the receiver, i am assigning the getDoubleExtra values to those static variables-  latitud & longitud

Answer (score 0):

it depends on, where you have unregistered your broadcast receiver, as your activity is in background you cannot update your `TextView` of your activity ,solution is to assign  the values to static variables and then update your `TextViews` in `onCreate()` or `onResume` method.